# How do I click on a button that makes an invisible button appear in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

I need to do a quiz with levels and I would like the next level button to appear only when a certain button was clicked, how to do it? (Please be detailed, because I'm new to java)

Comment: What have you tried until now? Can you post some code?

Comment: btn.setVisibility (View.GONE);

Comment: But only serves to do this that I want on the same screen

Comment: Please provide more details, including existing code examples and evidence of research around the question.

Comment: Please only use the [android-studio] tag if you have a question about the tool itself, **not** for general programming questions.

Comment: so sorry, I will avoid this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity A:

```
btnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                    i.putExtra("isAnswerCorrect",true);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

Activity B:

```
...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    boolean isAnswerCorrect = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isAnswerCorrect", false);
    if (isAnswerCorrect) {
        next_level_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        next_level_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

...
```

In this case, Activity A is where you are pressing the button and Activity B is the activity you are showing your next level button on,

Answer (score 2):

This should be in your java code:

```
      certain_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    button_next_level.setVisibility(View.Visible);
                }
            });
```

In your xml layout file, make the button_to_appear as gone.

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button_next_level"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

Comment: I was using a similar code, but does it only work only if the two buttons are on the same screen?

Comment: I am assuming that by same screen, you mean the same layout. And yes, it only works if they are in the same xml layout.

Comment: Yes, screens = layouts, but I'm having to do this with buttons in different layouts

Comment: So basically, you want to hide the button in another activity which contains the next level button on basis of button click in the activity with certain_button?

Comment: exactl, different activities

Comment: If you are launching one activity from another, then put a boolean IsButtonClicked variable in Intent and get it on the other activity. Check the variable in the other activity and put this : if(IsButtonClicked){button_next_level.setVisibility(View.Visible);}

Comment: If this solves your problem please accept my answer!

Comment: I'll accept your answer haha, but can you give me a better example showing xml and java of this idea?

Comment: Please share some code so that I can better understand your need. I will provide the answer accordingly.

Comment: aqui estão os prints do meu app, quero que o botão 1 do layout 1 quando apertado faça o botão 2 do layout 2 aparecer (ele estará invisivel, no caso) 
http://imageshack.com/a/img923/6508/0xMOt4.png
http://imageshack.com/a/img923/6923/nU2rfD.png